# Combine similar rows across two data frames

Tags: r

Still getting the gist of R. I have two data frames where the rows are named with different coordinates (e.g. x_1013y_41403; see below). The coordinates form sets of five, each set makes a cross if plotted onto a grid. The center coordinate is in one data frame, and the four peripheral coordinates are in the other.

```
Center                  A       B       C      D       E       F
x_723y_6363.txt       554      NA     604     NA     645      NA
x_749y_41403.txt       14      NA       6     NA      13      NA

Peripheral              A       B       C      D       E       F
x_1013y_41403.txt      NA       1      NA      0      NA       0
x_459y_6363.txt        NA       2      NA      1      NA       4
x_485y_41403.txt       NA       0      NA      0      NA       0
x_723y_6100.txt        NA       1      NA      0      NA       3
x_723y_6627.txt        NA       1      NA      0      NA       1
x_749y_41139.txt       NA       1      NA      0      NA       0
x_749y_41667.txt       NA       2      NA      0      NA       0
x_987y_6363.txt        NA       1      NA      0      NA       0
```

To form a set, the peripheral coordinates would have the same x or y location as the center coordinate. For example, the center coordinate x_723y_6363 would be associated with x_723y_6100 and x_723y_6627 (same x location), as well as x_459y_6363 and x_987y_6363 (same y location).

I would like to combine the coordinates into their respective sets, and name the set with the center coordinate. For the case above, I would end up with two rows, where each row is the summation of a set.

```
                        A       B       C      D       E       F
x_723y_6363.txt       554       5     604      1     645       8
x_749y_41403.txt       14       4       6      0      13       0
```

I am not sure at all how this can be done. I have thought about creating regular expressions to pick out the x and y coordinates individually and then doing a comparison across the two data frames. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `dput(head(Center))` and `dput(head(Peripheral))`?

Answer (score 1):

I hope someone else comes up with a better answer as this is ugly. I would first split the .txt names into x and y values then loop over each of the variables that is NA in center and sum all values that are share an x or y value with that center. **Edit:** Changed the `sapply` to make it slightly nicer.

```
center <- read.table(textConnection("                                                                                                                                                          
A B C D E F                                                                                                                                                                                    
x_723y_6363.txt       554      NA     604     NA     645      NA                                                                                                                               
x_749y_41403.txt       14      NA       6     NA      13      NA"),
                     header = TRUE)

peripheral <- read.table(textConnection("                                                                                                                                                      
A       B       C      D       E       F                                                                                                                                                       
x_1013y_41403.txt      NA       1      NA      0      NA       0                                                                                                                               
x_459y_6363.txt        NA       2      NA      1      NA       4                                                                                                                               
x_485y_41403.txt       NA       0      NA      0      NA       0                                                                                                                               
x_723y_6100.txt        NA       1      NA      0      NA       3                                                                                                                               
x_723y_6627.txt        NA       1      NA      0      NA       1                                                                                                                               
x_749y_41139.txt       NA       1      NA      0      NA       0                                                                                                                               
x_749y_41667.txt       NA       2      NA      0      NA       0                                                                                                                               
x_987y_6363.txt        NA       1      NA      0      NA       0"),
                         header = TRUE)

xpat <- "^([^y]+).*"
ypat <- ".*(y_[0-9]+)\\.txt"
center$x <- gsub(xpat, "\\1", rownames(center))
center$y <- gsub(ypat, "\\1", rownames(center))
peripheral$x <- gsub(xpat, "\\1", rownames(peripheral))
peripheral$y <- gsub(ypat, "\\1", rownames(peripheral))


vars <- c("B", "D", "F")

center[vars] <- sapply(peripheral[vars], function(col)
  apply(center, 1, function(row) sum(col[peripheral$x %in% row["x"] | peripheral$y %in% row["y"]]) )
  )

R> center
                    A B   C D   E F     x       y
 x_723y_6363.txt  554 5 604 1 645 8 x_723  y_6363
 x_749y_41403.txt  14 4   6 0  13 0 x_749 y_41403
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
# function to split coordinates x and y:

f <- function(DF) structure(
    t(sapply(strsplit(row.names(DF), "[_y.]"), `[`, c(2,4))),
    dimnames=list(NULL, c("x", "y")))

# get x and y for peripheral data:

P <- cbind(Peripheral, f(Peripheral))

# get x and y for centers, and mark ids:

C <- cbind(Center, f(Center), id=1:nrow(Center))

# matching:

Q <- merge(merge(P, C[,c("x","id")], all=TRUE), C[,c("y","id")], by="y", all=TRUE)

# prepare for union:

R <- within(Q, {id <- ifelse(is.na(id.y), id.x, id.y); id.x <- NULL; id.y <- NULL})

# join everything and aggregate:

S <- rbind(R, C)

aggregate(S[,3:8], by=list(id=S$id), FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Result:

```
  id   A B   C D   E F
1  1 554 5 604 1 645 8
2  2  14 4   6 0  13 0
```